# Webdriver & javascript: Getting web element by attribute name

Tags: javascript, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to get an web element by attribute name (async way)

```
<input name="Login" placeholder="Login" type="text">
```

In Webdriver v4 (legacy code) it is [documented](http://v4.webdriver.io/v3.4/guide/usage/selectors.html#Name-Attribute) as the following:

```
$('input[name="Login"]')
```

I'm using webdriver v5> where it is not working 
(element not found) and [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html) doesn't explain how to proceed in cases like that (or maybe I'm just not finding it)

What I am missing here?

Comment: What means `not working` ? You getting some exception?

Comment: @Xotabu4 - you right. I put extra information in my post. It's async mode and the error is that it cannot find the element.

Answer (score 1):

ok ... the sintaxe is ok. what I was failing of was the missing **await** in front of selector. The element doesn't exist when this line was reached, then when I tried to set a value I got an error.

```
let user = await $('input[name="Login"]')
```

I realized that logging the value of user:

Without await:

```
>>>>>>> [object Promise]
```

With await:

```
>>>>>>> [object Object]
```

Without await it is hard to know when the elemeent was not rendered yet or it is just wrong.

Any suggestion on how to handle it in a better/more elegant way will be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Question: Are you using WDIO in standalone mode or with runner file approach? Basically WDIO has ways to run the code synchronously. You need to pick an option  based on the mode you are using it.

Comment: Thats all about your configuration - if you using WDIO in sync mode - you don't need to worry about async/await. Without it - you need to handle async code execution order by yourself - by putting await for all your async commands.